# Cache mysql db table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a big mysql (innodb) table, which have ~3million of rows....
My vps hosting has 3gb of RAM...

Are there any ways to send this table to RAM memory, so that i can get speed up of getting information from this db?

I have "tuned-up" my mysql so that i can get keys in cache up to 512mb....  But main trouble is that only once this row is fetched i cache it....   But how can i cache all table, or send it to RAM memory "by one click"?

I read some about memory type of mysql, but i must have data all time, but not to delete when server is rebooted....

So how to send mysql table to RAM memory?

Comment: What is the problem you want solve? Is your application too slow right now?

Comment: @Jocelyn  yes, a little bit to slow, when operating with disk-based table